# Show Customer's Data in Jtable using Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I want show customer details from a MySQL database in a JTable, but I don't see any result in my panel when I click the "show" button.

This is the method to add the table to the JScrollPane:

```
    void addTable()
    {
        for(int i=0 ; i<myTableModel.getColumnCount();i++)
        {
            myTableModel.getColumnName(i);
        }
       showCustomers();
       table.setModel(myTableModel);//mytablemodel is a object from MyTableModel Class
       scrollPane.add(table); //was on another part of program but i edit it for helping to answers                 
       panel_show.add(scrollPane);
    }
```

And here is `MyTableClass`, implementing TableModel, with a new method, `addCustomer`. `addCustomer` will add a Customer to the CustomerList. I am trying ArrayList for first time to show Customer data but it doesn't work.

Also, `columnName` will make the table headers with the column names from the database.

```
public class MyTableModel implements TableModel
{
    private ArrayList<Customer> customerList;
    private String[] columnName =          
     {"id", "name", "family", "idc", "age", "sex", "balance", "tel", "haveFamily", "population"};
@Override
public int getRowCount()
{
    //return customerList.size();
      return 1;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount()
{
    return 10;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int columnIndex)
{
    return columnName[columnIndex];
}

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex)
{
    if(columnIndex == 0)
        return Integer.class;
    return String.class;
}

@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
{
    if(columnIndex == 0)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getId();
    else if(columnIndex == 1)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getName();
    else if(columnIndex == 2)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getFamily();
    else if(columnIndex == 3)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getIdc();
    else if(columnIndex == 4)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getDate();
    else if(columnIndex == 5)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getSex();
    else if(columnIndex == 6)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getBalance();
    else if(columnIndex == 7)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getTel();
    else if(columnIndex == 8)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).isHaveFamily();
    else if(columnIndex == 9)
        return customerList.get(rowIndex).getPopulation();
    else
        return null;
}

public void addCustomer(Customer customer)
{
    CustomerManager customerManager = new CustomerManager();
    customerManager.addCustomer(customer);
    customerList.add(customer);
}
```

The `showCustomer` method will be open a database connection and create a TableModel with customers, which is then used for the table on my panel.

```
    public void showCustomers()
    {
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
        //String user = "root";
        // String pass = null;
        //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/estate";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/estate", "root", null);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * from customer");
        //int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        while (rs.next())
        {
            myTableModel.addCustomer(new Customer(1,"david","schmidt","0025674433","31","Male","200000","4545552132","true","2");               
     }//Original Form --> Customer({"id","name","family","idc","age",
      // "sex","balance","tel","haveFamily","population"});
    }
```

In `MyTableModel` I make an `addCustomer` method and fill the customer data using a ResultSet. Is it needed?

### My question: How can I show my Customers using a JTable?

After some fiddling I now also have a problem with `myTableModel.addCustomer(rs.getInt(), ...)`. The error I am getting is this:

> Error in addCustomer,Duplicate entry '0' for KEY PRIMARY

However, I don't have a customer with an ID of 0.

Comment: actually i do what i can to do with each ways and ideas in my mind,but i don't want make it worked!i just want make it worked in new style's and better Programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When displaying a JTable you first add the table to a scroll pane and then you add the scroll pane to a panel.
2. When adding a component to a visible GUI you need to make sure the layout manager has been invoked so that the component has a size and location.

So the basic code would be:

```
table.setModel(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
panel.add( scrollPane );
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

The other approach is the create an empty table and add the scroll pane to the GUI when you first create the GUI. Then all the code you need is:

```
table.setModel(...);
```

Edit:

You question is about displaying a table in a panel, when you click a button. So that is ALL the SSCCE should do. Where the data comes from is irrelevant, so posting code dealing with a database is completely unnecessary, because we can't execute the code. A custom TableModel is irrelevant to the real question.

Here is a simple SSCCE that uses my second suggestion of updating an existing table with a new model. Every time you click the button the number of columns changes. This `simulates` getting new data from somewhere.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class RefreshSSCCE extends JPanel
{
    private JTable table = new JTable();
    private int columns = 3;

    public RefreshSSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JButton refresh = new JButton( "Refresh Data" );
        add(refresh, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        refresh.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                refreshData();
            }
        });

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void refreshData()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(5, columns++);
        table.setModel( model );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Refresh SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new RefreshSSCCE() );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See how easy that code is to understand? The code is complete and in one class. It can easily be copied and pasted so others can test the code.

When you simplify the problem then solution is usually much easier. That is why you take the time to create a `SSCCE`. Even if the SSCCE doesn't work the way you want, we only have a couple of lines of code to look at to understand what you are attempting to do. There is no need to complicate the question with SQL code.

Once you get the simple code working you then modify the `refreshData` method to get real data. That is what I mean by hardcoding data. There is no need for a dynamic query of the database to demonstrate your problem of displaying a table in a panel.

Comment: i have scrollpane in my panel,it doesn't worked,somewhere in my code is wrong for showing data

Comment: @MR1, you still don't revalidate() and repaint() the panel. If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. Note, we don't have access to your database so just replace that code with hard coded data so we can compile and execute the SSCCE.

Comment: yes,but i have an example don't use that methods and still worked in SQLServer,but that project is not mine,and i have my style,thank you and i will make what you said and edit my codes soon.

Comment: what i should to do?where's the problem?!i'm waiting ,tnx

Comment: Based on the information provide, I told you the fix. Since you haven't posted a proper `SSCCE` I can't give any more help.

Comment: Excuse me,how can i posted a proper SSCCE?!,i try to use hardcoding in my code's,should i do something else?tnx

Comment: i use that methods(revalidate() , repaint()) but i have problem with my Constructor for passing data to it and pass the object to myTableModel and also i don't think my code's for showing are correct because i never seen JTable with Data in my project

Comment: @MR1, I give up!!! A verbal description does not help us. I showed you how to create a SSCCE. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: it's ok,thank you,i will be happy learn SSCCE,thanks for your answers